# how to install SQL 2000 in windows server 2016 OS

Tags: sql-server-2000, windows-server

how to install SQL 2000 in windows server 2016 OS, Is it possible ,please give me a solution.

Comment: Nope. Install on an operating system that officially supports 2000, and then upgrade the operating system. Or don't use SQL Server 2000.

Comment: our application software's back end created with SQL 2000 did not support other version of sql

Comment: SQL 2000 is not supported on Windows Server 2016. You can create a virtual machine with windows XP using Hyper-V and install SQL 2000 on it.

Comment: Do you have other Server instances and versions of SQL that you can use? 2008 +

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend that you take the time and effort required to connect your app to a newer version of SQL, preferably one that is officially supported. i.e 2012+. (SQL 2000, 2005 and 2008 and 2008R2 are all officially obsolete.)

If you have issues with deprecated features or connectivity, SQL 2008R2   supports database compatibility back to 2000. It's still obsolete, but is still a much more sophisticated product than 2000.

Edit: Technically Support for 2008 & 2008R2 is still available from Microsoft through their [MS Lifecycle Support Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=SQL%20Server%202008).

In most cases apps are oblivious to which version of SQL they are on as long as they can connect and the features and functions still work.

Even if you can't do a backup and restore, you should be able to create a new db and use SSIS to import the data. If this is a current application I highly recommend you go back to the vendors for assistance and ask/insist they support current db's. Requiring a 17 yr old db to be able to install or run their software is terrible.

If this is a legacy app and no longer supported I suspect you have a much bigger issue looming than just moving a db.

If this is a legacy app and you just want to keep it running but need to replace hardware, I would consider virtualising the server.

Comment: I have an app where the developers constrained it to only install on an instance of SQL Server where the version is 2008 or 2008R2.  So stupid.

Comment: I'm sure it made sense.. on the day.. to someone... somewhere... ;)

Comment: Your comment about SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 no longer being supported is not fully correct. If you have an Enterprise Agreement with Microsoft then you have support for both products (Extended Support) until 7/9/2019 with the correct SPs: [MS Lifecycle Support Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=SQL%20Server%202008). You can even apply for 6 years of additional [Premium Assurance](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2016/12/08/introducing-windows-server-premium-assurance-and-sql-server-premium-assurance/) should you have such requirements.